# MySQL latest unique user chats not working

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get latest created datetime for unique user_id. I've got below query but it does not seem to be working....It does not get the latest created time.

```
SELECT * FROM `chats` 
WHERE receiver_id = 1
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY created DESC
```

Is there a reason why?

**UPDATE:**

Actually I found my answer myself. Please look below. I had to use INNER JOIN for nested searched and filtered result table then find using where clause of that result then left join on that table to get the data I needed!

```
SELECT c.*, users.username 
FROM chats c 
INNER JOIN( 
SELECT MAX(created) AS Date, user_id, receiver_id, chat, type, id 
FROM chats 
WHERE receiver_id = 1 
GROUP BY user_id ) cc ON cc.Date = c.created AND cc.user_id = c.user_id 
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = c.user_id 
WHERE c.receiver_id = 1
```

Comment: You'll probably want to post your table structure here.

Comment: Can you give us more info about your problem? For instance, what's the structure of the chats table, and perhaps some sample data from that table.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [MAX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) aggregate function -

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(created) latest_datetime FROM chats
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Try this query, it will show all users and latest created datetime.

Comment: This works only when you need to show grouped and aggregated field. Otherwise, when other fields should be shown, you should use group-wise query - like you wrote in the question.